# in django I want to remove employee name one by one after successfull attendence submition

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want onclick of update button the submitted attendence of employee should not display in the list.
I mean it should be removed one by one after successfull submition of attendence of employees.

My model of employee attendence is

```
class Attendence(models.Model):
    EmpId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='EmpId')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Name')
    Site = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Site')
    #month = models.ForeignKey(Month,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='month')
    #year = models.ForeignKey(Year,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='year')
    Days = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Days')
    Nh = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Nh')
    #SingleOt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='SingleOt',null=True)
    DoubleOt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='DobleOt',null=True)
    choices = [('P','Present'),('A','Absent'),('L','Leave')]
    Status = models.CharField(choices=choices,blank = False,max_length=10,verbose_name='Status')
    date = date.today()
    AttendenceOn = models.DateField(default = date)
```

My view.py look like below

```
def AttendenceList(request):
    attendencelist = Attendence.objects.filter(AttendenceOn=date.today()) 
    return render(request,"attendencelist.html", 
                          {"attendencelist":attendencelist,"date":date.today()})
def AttendenceView(request):

     Emp_list = EmployeeRegistration.objects.filter(Status='Working',
                                                    Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site).order_by('- 
                                                                                               Doj')
     if request.method == 'POST':
        empid = request.POST['empid']
        name = request.POST['name']
        status = request.POST.get('Status')
        ot = request.POST.get('DoubleOt')
        site = request.user.SuperVisor.Site
        if status is "P":
            day = 1

        Attendence.objects.create(EmpId=empid,
                                 Name=name,Status=status,Site=site,DoubleOt=ot,Days=day,Nh=0)

        attendForm = AttendForm()
        return redirect('show')
    else:
        attendForm = AttendForm()
        context = {"emp_list":Emp_list,
               "attendform":attendForm,
               "date":date.today()
               }

        return render(request,"attendence.html",context)
```

and my Template of attendence.html is given below

```
{% extends 'profilebase.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 15px;">
<div class="card">
<h1 class="card-header bg-info">Attendence <p style="float: right;">{{date}}</p></h1>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>                       
                            <th>Role</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Ot</th>
                            <th>Action</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for employee in emp_list %}

                                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'attendence' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>                        
                                    <td><input type="text" name="empid" value="{{employee.EmpId}}" 
   readonly="readonly"> </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{employee.Name}}" readonly="readonly"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="Designation" value="{{employee.Designation|capfirst}}" readonly="readonly"></td>
                                    <td>{{attendform.Status|as_crispy_field}}</td>
                                    <td>{{attendform.DoubleOt|as_crispy_field}}</td>

                                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>

                                </tr>
                            </form>

                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

My Employee attendence system screanshot is given below

[image: Employee attendence system]

Please help me Suggest me what can i do.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but do you want the row containing employee name to not be visible when you fill the form and click update?

Here's what you can do: 
1. Use JavaScript to hide the given row after you click update 
2. If you're reloading the page, write your SQL query in such a way that you don't fetch the updated row after it gets updated.

Comment: Thank you sir,
for your valuable suggestion. But You are to late .
I just added some more code in My view.py and Its worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def AttendenceView(request):
    # Get all employee list of working employee according to supervisor site 
    location
    Emp_list = 
    EmployeeRegistration.objects.filter(Status='Working',                          
    Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site).order_by('Name')
    # Check whether the method is POST or NOT
    if request.method == 'POST':
        empid = request.POST['empid'] # Get Employee Id from form
        name = request.POST['name']   # Get Employee Name from form
        status = request.POST.get('Status') # Get Employee Status whether he/she is 
        present or not from form
        ot = request.POST.get('DoubleOt')   # Get Employee Ot
        site = request.user.SuperVisor.Site
        if status is "P":
        day = 1 # If Employee is Present count day is equal to 1
        check = Attendence.objects.filter(EmpId=empid,
                       AttendenceOn=date.today()).exists() 
        # Check if Employee attendence has been submitted on current date of not)
        if(check == False):
            # If not found then save the attendence of employee
            Attendenceobj = AttendForm()
            attendobj = Attendenceobj.save(commit=False)
            attendobj.EmpId=empid
            attendobj.Name=name
            attendobj.Status=status
            attendobj.Site=site
            attendobj.DoubleOt=ot
            attendobj.Days=day
            attendobj.Nh=0
            attendobj.save() 
        else:
            # If Attendence already found then update the Employee attendence
            obj = Attendence.objects.get(EmpId=empid)
            obj.Name=name
            obj.Status=status
            #obj.Site=site
            obj.DoubleOt=ot
            obj.Days=day
            obj.Nh=0
            obj.save()
            #attendForm = AttendForm()
            # On Successful updation of attendence redirect ot Attendence List
            return redirect('show')
   else:
        attendForm = AttendForm()
        registerobj = EmployeeRegistration.objects.all().order_by('Name')
        Emp_list = []
        for employee in registerobj:
            attendenceobj = 
            Attendence.objects.filter(EmpId=employee.EmpId,AttendenceOn=date.today())
            if attendenceobj.exists():
               pass
            else:
                Emp_list.append(employee)

    context = {"emp_list":Emp_list,
               "attendform":attendForm,
               "date":date.today()
               }

    return render(request,"attendence.html",context)
```